# Convert utf-8 chracters in a file to hex

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8

There are some utf-8 characters in a text file, I want to process them and convert them into hex format, write their hex values written into another file, what is the best way to do this?
I know of wstring, wchar but they cant store utf-8 characters, char16_t and char32_t can store but they dont support iostream. Some poeple suggested using the ICU Library but the requirement is that it's best not to use the external libraries.

Comment: You need to dig in and understand utf-8. To answer your question, just read the file in binary sequentially and dump the octets out

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use external libraries then you basically have two options:

- Parse the bytes yourself.
- [`MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can use `MultiByteToWideChar` if the file is small enough to fit in memory. If there are any codepoints outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) then you have to deal with surrogate pairs.

Parsing yourself is not that hard either if you know how to test and shift bits in a byte. Wikipedia has a pretty [good article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) that provides most of the details...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

`int ascii_to_utf8(unsigned char c, char * out)
{
       int len = 0;
       char x = 0;
       if(c < 128)
       {
             out[0] = c;
             len = 1;
       }
       else
       {
             out[0] = (c >> 6) | 0xC0;
             out[1] = (c & 0x3F) | 0x80;
             len = 2;
       }
       return len;
}`

int utf8_to_ascii(unsigned char * c, char * out)
{
       int len = 1;
       if(*c > 0xC0)
       {
             * out = (( c[0] << 6 ) & 0xC0 ) | ( c[1] & 0x3F );
             len = 2;
       }
       else
       {
             * out = * c;
       }
       return len;
}